# Display random records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, random, records

I'm experimenting with Rails and wanted to display an array in an array, this works; code of index.html.erb beneath:

```
<div id="events">
  <% @events.each_with_index do |event, i| %>
    <%= link_to event_path(event) do %>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<%= event.image.url %>')"></div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2><%= event.name %></h2>
        <div class="location"><%= event.location %></div>
        <date><strong><%= l event.date_start, :format => :day %> – <%= l event.date_end, :format => :day %> <%= l event.date_end, :format => :month %> </strong><%= l event.date_end, :format => :year %></date>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <%if i%1 == 1 %>
      <% @ads.find(:first) do |ad| %>
        <%= ad.name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%if (i+1)%4 == 0 %>
      <% @ads.find(:first) do |ad| %>
        <a href="<%= ad.url %>" target="_blank" class="ad">
          <div class="card">
            <%= ad.name %>
          </div>
        </a>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And events_controller:

```
def index
  @ads = Ad.all.shuffle
end
```

Works pretty nice so far, after 4 @events items I get one @ads, random. However all @ads
items are always the same random one.

How can I display random @ads items through the page without having the same one twice?

Comment: "@ads items are always the same random one". `@ads.find(:first)` - you have a very flexible definition of "random" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yeah, I'm still pretty new to this. However picking the first one of a random array works pretty decent so far.

Comment: @user2861994 Can you try sample method - Ad.all.sample

Comment: @Icicle it gives me a "NoMethodError": undefined method `find' for #<Ad:0x007f84b97dbd20>

Comment: @user2861994 That method won't work on your model object. sample is method of array.

Comment: @Icicle How do you mean?

Comment: Do you want to display random add then you can do using this code - Ad.all.sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
def index
  @ads = Ad.all.shuffle
end
```

You could use

```
def index
  @ads = Ad.all.to_a.shuffle
end
```

while store all your `Ad` records in an array, shuffled

Then in your view, instead of

```
<% @ads.find(:first) do |ad| %>
  <%= ad.name %>
<% end %>
```

You could use

```
<% ad = @ads.pop %>
<%= ad.name %>
```

Which get you one `Ad`, and remove it from the array, so you won't get it a second time

Note we don't use a block in this case

Note also that when your array is empty, `ad.name` will raise `NoMethodError`, so you need to check on that too

Answer (score 1):

Try changing instances of `@ads.find(:first)` to `@ads.pop` - [pop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pop) removes an item from the array and returns it - further calls to that array won't have the 'popped' item any more.

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]
a.pop     #=> "d"
a.pop(2)  #=> ["b", "c"]
a         #=> ["a"]
```

Comment: If I try pop it displays no @ads

Comment: don't use @ads.pop{}.  try `<% add = @ads.pop %>` then `<a href="<%= ad.url %>" target="_blank" class="ad">`.

Comment: Like this?       
    <% add = @ads.pop %>
        <a href="<%= ad.url %>" target="_blank" class="ad">
          <div class="card">
            <%= ad.name %>
          </div>
        </a>
      <% end %>